# How to SELECT all occurrences of all duplicate rows with all columns from a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

For example:

```
select c1, c2
from mytable
group by c1, c2
having count(*) > 1;
```

will give only 1 copy each of the duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by c1, c2) as cnt
      from mytable
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Note that this works even when `c1` and/or `c2` are `NULL`.

However, if you only care about `c1` and `c2`, then perhaps including the count in the result set is sufficient:

```
select c1, c2, count(*)
from mytable
group by c1, c2
having count(*) > 1;
```

Another fun method in Oracle:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (select 1
              from mytable t2
              where t2.c1 = t.c1 and t2.c2 = t.c2 and t2.rowid <> t.rowid
             );
```

However, this fails if either `c1` or `c2` is `NULL`, so the first method is more general.

Comment: select c1, c2, count(*)
from mytable
group by c1, c2
having count(*) > 1;
wont this still display only 1 copy per group , but what i need is all dup rows from the group .

Comment: @AjinkyaPujari . . . That is what the other two queries do.  I just mentioned including `count(*)`, because might might be sufficient for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

add SQL with all c1/c2 values

```
with dup as (
select c1,c2 from mytable group by c1,c2 having count(*) > 1
)
select c1,c2 from mytable m, dup where m.c1=dup.c1 and m.c2 = c2.dup;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
select * from mytable mt join (select c1, c2 from mytable group by c1, c2 having count(*) > 1) m on mt.c1=m.c1 and mt.c2 = m.c2